# Laravel if request on view (with help from route)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I do the request on view because I want to disable some parts and for some pages:

```
@if (\Request::route()->getName() != 'product.show')
```

This works, but my question is, can I set a additional parameter on my route to make my script more flexibile, something like:

My route code is:

```
Route::get('/product/{slug}', ['uses' => 'ProductController@show', 'NO_SIDEBAR_PARAM' => 'true'], function ($slug) {
    return [$slug];
})->name('product.show');
```

So I want to create if request on "NO_SIDEBAR_PARAM" if is set to "true" or "false" to enable or disable elements.

Is the way correct?

Comment: If you're only applying this logic to the one show method in the product controller, the simplest thing to do would be to have the controller method pass along a 'sidebar' variable with a truthy value. And then have ur view check for that variable being truthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) to set view variables that I want to have available in most views. It might help solve your issue too.

```
class SetViewVariables
{
    /** @var SideBarBuilder */
    private $builder;

    public function __construct(SideBarBuilder $builder)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->route()->name() == 'product.show') {
            view()->share('sidebar', '');
        } else {
            view()->share('sidebar', $this->builder->makeSideBar());
        }
    }
}
```

In this example the SideBarBuilder is your own class that generates the sidebar. I just like using Laravels container to resolve such simple classes.